# How do I save and show text input to local storage using a button

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I am trying save the value of the text inputs to local storage after a user enters it using a button. Once they save it, they click another button to show the contents of local storage in another text area. I've tried every method I could think of. Thanks in advance.

```js
    <script>
                function add_local(){
                  window.localStorage['display'] = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
                  window.localStorage['display']= document.getElementById('age').value;
                  window.localStorage['display']= document.getElementById('course').value;
                }
                function show_local(){
                  document.getElementById('firstname').value = window.localStorage['display'];
                  document.getElementById('age').value = window.localStorage['display'];
                  document.getElementById('course').value = window.localStorage['display'];
                }
          </script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstname" /><br /><br /> <label for="age">Age</label><br />
<input type="text" id="age" /><br /><br /> <label for="course">Favorite Course</label><br /> <input type="text" id="course" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <input type="button" value="Add to localStorage" onclick="add_local()" />
          <input type="button" value="Add to sessionStorage" />
          <input type="button" value="Show localStorage" onclick="show_local()"/>
          <input type="button" value="Show sessionStorage" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="display">
        <label for="display">Display</label><br>
        <textarea id="display" name="display" rows="10" ></textarea>
</div>
    </div>
      
  </body>
```

Comment: In your `add_local` you are adding the name to localStorage and then modifying it with the value of age and course.

Comment: @aerial301 How would I be able to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

in local storage you have method to set and get

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

like

```
    localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');

    const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

with those method you save to localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You did almost everything right. Just replace the following JS code with your js. You just made replacing your old storage data while assigning with a new one.

```
   function add_local() {
    window.localStorage['firstname'] = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    window.localStorage['age'] = document.getElementById('age').value;
    window.localStorage['course'] = document.getElementById('course').value;
}

function show_local() {
    document.getElementById('firstname').value = window.localStorage['firstname'];
    document.getElementById('age').value = window.localStorage['age'];
    document.getElementById('course').value = window.localStorage['course'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   function add_local() {
   const display = {};
   display.firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
   display.age = document.getElementById('age').value;
   display.course = document.getElementById('course').value;

   window.localStorage.setItem('display', JSON.stringify(display));
   

 }
```

and for show try this :

```
 function show_local() {

   let _display = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("display"));
   document.getElementById('firstname').value = _display.firstname;
   document.getElementById('age').value = _display.age;
   document.getElementById('course').value = _display.course;
   document.getElementById('display').value = Object.values(_display);
  
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3tj8okxm/

Comment: I'm assuming that it saves to the local storage but it doesn't output the name, age and course to the display text area.

Comment: for show data to display text area try this :     document.getElementById('display').value = Object.values(_display);